# Undefined name 'storage'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm makiing a mthod to Retrieve image from firebase storage,please tell me how i can solve this error

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _loadImage() async {
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> files = [];
    
        final ListResult result = await storage.ref('pizza').list();//Undefined name 'storage'.
    Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
        final List<Reference> allFiles = result.items;
    
        await Future.forEach<Reference>(allFiles, (file) async {
          final String fileUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
          final FullMetadata fileMeta = await file.getMetadata();
          files.add({
            "url": fileUrl,
          });
        });
    
        return files;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the definition of the `storage` variable. Did you just copy-paste this into your code from somewhere? Try using `FirebaseStorage.instance` instead.

Comment: if i use FirebaseFirestore.instance then how i can give the refrence of image folder

Comment: ok i use this FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance; it work thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Just updated the answer with the correct class name. Please mark the answer as accepted once it's confirmed.